# How to draw a figure with multiple subfigures and parts in common?

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to make a figure in LaTeX to explain modulation. By any chance, do you know how to plot this ?
[image: modulation]
I know how to plot one figure, but not to add the binary values on top, nor putting the delimitating lines on all the curves... timing representation of modulation

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SE. "Do this figure for me" question aren't allowed here, as this isn't a free support service. To do this sort of figure, you should TikZ, which is a package providing powerful commands to make figures in LaTeX. Then try what you can, and ask questions about the problems you have with it. Thank you.

Comment: You can put more than on axis environment into a pgfplots tikzpicture.  Using [name=...] on one axis and [shift=...] on another you could get them to line up.

Comment: Found the solution here :
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590387/binary-sequence-to-nrz-ask-fsk-using-tikz